# Get ChangeSets using REST API (Azure DevOps Tfvc) of specific branch in asp.net 6

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, tfvc, changeset

I want to get ChangeSets of specific branch by using Azure DevOps API.
[This is how we can get using UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApvMg.png) but I need to get same thing using API.
Right now I am doing like

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/TestRepo/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "Token here");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://dev.azure.com/TestRepo/TestProject/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$skip=0&$top=200&api-version=6.0").Result;}
```

This is fetching ChangeSets of all branches but I need to get of specific branch.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the TFVC path you want to get changesets for in the request URL: searchCriteria.itemPath=

```
https://dev.azure.com/TestRepo/TestProject/_apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.itemPath=<item path/>&api-version=6.0
```